# Orika data mapping error after installing cmsoccaddon on custom commercewebservices on Hybris 2005

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We are using the custom commercewebservice extended from ycommercewebservice. We are not using the CMS API as of now but we have we need CMS APIs for spartacus.

I have install **cmsoccaddon** on our customer webservice extension. Addon install successfully but when we try to access https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/{base_site}/cms/pages it will throws the error:

`ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: While attempting the following mapping: sourceType = de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.data.PageContentSlotData sourceProperty = slotShared(boolean) destinationType = java.util.ArrayList<ContentSlotWsDTO> destinationProperty = 8(ContentSlotWsDTO) Error occurred: ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: Encountered mapping of primitive to object (or vise-versa); sourceType=boolean, destinationType=ContentSlotWsDTO`

Fetch component API is working fine with the cmsaddon (https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/{base_site}/cms/components?fields=DEFAULT&componentIds={componentId})

We Just update hybris version to 2005

Answer (score 0):

Since you migrated from 1905 to 2005, the endpoints prefix has been changed from `/rest/v2/` to `/occ/v2`.

More information can be found in the following:

help.sap (2005) https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/e5d7cec9064f453b84235dc582b886da/d46d19516961438f8939718e87ed787b.html?version=2005
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/9136088a207c4fc1bb5ec2b53c462b23.html?version=2005